# Prevent an iframe from stealing focus

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a website that embeds an iframe.  When I was testing the iframe, I used google.com and noticed the search input field took focus.  Clearly, I won't be using google.com for production but would like to prevent the iframe from stealing focus.

Is there a way to prevent an iframe from stealing focus?

Answer (score 6):

If you have access to server side scripting you can use it to download a live copy of the page you want to embed, search it and remove any focus stealing code, then display that modified page in your iframe. Or if you find there is no focus stealing code, you can just link your iframe to the remote page as usual.

Another option might be to initially hide the iframe with CSS `style="display:none"` and allow the user to unhide it with javascript `Object.style.display="inline"`

Comment: I recommend loading the iframe initially with "display:none;".  Then once the iframe has loaded you can set display=block [and then if you'd like you can also remove the onload property to stop it from firing again and again]  
iframe.setAttribute('onload',    'javascript:var a=document.getElementById("iframe");a.style.display="block";a.setAttribute("onload","");');

Answer (score 3):

You could poll the document's active element. If it happens to be an `<iframe>`, you can call the `blur()` function to restore the previously focused element:

```js
setInterval(_ => {
    if (document.activeElement.tagName == "IFRAME") {
        document.activeElement.blur();
    }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `setTimeout` function to refocus on an element of your choice, e.g. 
`window.onload = function(){ setTimeout( function() { element.focus() }, 500 ) };`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here:

[Disable Body/Content Scrolling With jQuery - disableScroll](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Disable-Scrolling-jQuery-disableScroll.html)

Disabling scrolling stopped the iframe from stealing the focus.

I used this in my jquery script:

```
if( $('iframe').length != 0 ) $(window).disablescroll();

window.addEventListener('touchstart', function onFirstTouch() 
{
window.removeEventListener('touchstart', onFirstTouch, false);
AllowScrolling()
}, false);

$(window).on("scroll",function(){ $(window).off("scroll"); AllowScrolling() });

setTimeout(AllowScrolling,5000); //Fallback
function AllowScrolling(){$(window).disablescroll('undo')}
```

So if a user touches the screen or clicks the scroll bar, scrolling is permitted.
Seemed to work ok for me.

Comment: Don't encourage people to use the deprecated `eval` version of `setTimeout` by passing strings. You can do this better by simply passing the function reference instead of an `eval` string. `setTimeout(AllowScrolling, 5000)`.

Answer (score 0):

You may wait for the `onload` event on `iframe` to set `focus()` back to `body`, but if you come from a link reaching a specific anchor/id of the page, it might not a good idea.

A possibility more alike a CSS trick is to set `iframe` in `fixed` `position` untill it is loaded, then back to `static` (or the original position or your style sheet).

simple test to perform if that suits your needs :

```
iframe {position:fixed}
```

along with

```
  window.onload = function() {
  for (let iframe of document.querySelectorAll("iframe")) {
    iframe.style.position = "static";
  }
};
```

here is a codepen for test : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gOpXwzY  *(comment below  here if the link or iframe is broken)*

Answer (score -1):

Not really. You can put the focus back on your window if the focus moves away (**WARNING: I don't recommend using that code**):

```
<body onblur="window.focus();">
```

This has some not so nice side-effects like not being able to focus the location bar in Firefox or getting into endless loops if the frame also tries to fight for the focus. So if you want to do this (that's a big "if", I don't recommend it) you should at least limit it to the page loading phase and allow the focus to be changed after that.