# Prevent iFrame from getting focus when its src has an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this simple iframe:

```
<iframe src='http://edition.cnn.com/2014/05/23/world/asia/thai-coup-color-day-2/index.html?hpt=hp_c1#cnnContentContainer' class='ExFrame' id='ifr' style='width:100%;height:500px;' scrolling='yes'>
```

But when I load the page, the iframe gets the focus. Is it possible to prevent this?
I tried this:

```
$("#ifr").blur();
```

With no luck...

http://jsfiddle.net/ELRxm/

EDIT: I want to use the #ID in the iframe's url

Comment: I don't know if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208064/prevent-an-iframe-from-stealing-focus?rq=1

Comment: How can you tell that its taking the focus?

Comment: I believe the problem may have something to do with you the src you are using (there may be some magic in that page's javascript).

Comment: @AlexThomas see page scrolling

Comment: See if that fits your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/X8CE8/1/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The [sandbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh563496.aspx) attribute solved my problem

Comment: How did it solve your problem, specifically? I wouldn't have accepted that as an answer, myself ;)

Comment: Barney: it is usually script in the iframe's document that switches focus to one of its elements. By setting the iframe's 'sandbox' attribute ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox ) to a value that does not contain the flag 'allow-scripts' then the iframe is prevented from running script, which prevents it from grabbing focus. Of course, whether this is an acceptable solution depends on whether disabling script in the iframe has other undesirable consequences. But for some scenarios this will work well.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to check the Javascript to see what is going on with the frame; it may be setting the focus.

By eliminating the javascript in your code:

```
$("#ifr").blur();
```

, and changing the `src`I found the focus just remains okay in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sablefoste/8gtLW/1/

*** EDIT ***

Per @A. Wolff's comment, the `#` tells the browser to focus on the specific content.  But you should watch for both this and Javascript in website's you don't own, they can both make a difference.

Comment: Yes it seems to be because of that particular website.

Comment: Specifically, I see several focus events related to the src file http://z.cdn.turner.com/cnn/tmpl_asset/static/www_article/1876/js/artlib-min.js

Comment: It's because I'm using #id at the end of the iframe's url

Comment: That's because of the hash in URL which put specific element into view: `#cnnContentContainer`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `#cnnContentContainer` at the end of the url:

```
<iframe src='http://edition.cnn.com/2014/05/23/world/asia/thai-coup-color-day-2/index.html?hpt=hp_c1' class='ExFrame' id='ifr' style='width:100%;height:500px;' scrolling='yes'></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ELRxm/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `setTimeout()` with something like 500ms to change the focus to an element of your choice.